# Замена части элемента списка на часть элемента этого же списка

Tags: python, list

есть список
`a = ["12", "34"]`
как из его получить список 
`a = ["123", "34"]`

к 1 элементу добавляется половина 2 элемента.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее, приведите примеры.

Comment: точно. Забыл сказать, к 1 элементу добавляется половина 2 элемента.

Comment: @АртёмКрылов А если элементов больше 2-х? Если их `n`?

Comment: не влияет, только два элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ["12", "34"]

a[0] += a[1][:len(a[1]) // 2]

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
['123', '34']
```

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто. Вот так:

```
a[0] = "123"
```

Comment: а если неизвестен второй элемент?

Comment: А если неизвестен второй элемент, то техзадание непонятно. А если техзадание непонятно, то остается только тучи развести руками. Тут и так непонятно, причем тут вообще второй элемент.